# Unzip and Rename underlying File using Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage

Possible to rename an underlying file while Unzipping using Logic App? I am calling an HTTP activity to download a ZIP file. That Zip contains only 1 Underlying file with some value appended to the name. I want to store the Unzipped file with a better name so that it can be used further.  Is it possible ?

Incoming ZIP File --> SAMPLEFile.ZIP

Underlying File --> SampleTextFile20200824121212.TXT

Desired File --> SampleTextFile.TXT

[image]

Suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, we can't implement this requirement directly in "Extract archive to folder" action. We can just rename the file by copy it from one folder to another folder (shown as below).

[image]

You can create a new ticket on [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps) page to ask azure team for this feature.

Comment: Thanks Shen for the solution.